# Preventing Spiders on One Subdomain?

Tags: subdomain, google-search, robots.txt

We currently host multiple sites on the same domain that all live in the same physical directory on the server. Each is database driven and lives at a unique subdomain. For example, site1.example.com, site2.example.com, etc. However, because all of these sites live in the same directory, they share a robots.txt file.

I would like to set up a test/demo site on this same codebase(i.e. demo.example.com), but I do not want it to be indexed by search engines. Is there any way that I can configure robots.txt to disallow an entire subdomain while not affecting other subdomains that live in the same physical location?

Comment: you can't use a robots.txt to do this directly but you could use a rewrite rule to serve a different version of robots.txt base on incoming URL. I have not given his as an answer as I don't know how to make the rewrite rule. someone else will...

Comment: Thanks for this comment - it pointed me in the right direction. I submitted the rule that is working for me as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using `mod_rewrite` to accomplish what I need:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^demo\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots-demo\.txt

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^demo\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots-othersites\.txt
```

Comment: Yep, gotta wait another 19 hours before I can. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can configure the subdomain site to send an additional [X-Robots-tag](http://code.google.com/web/controlcrawlindex/docs/robots_meta_tag.html) HTTP header, assuming that each subdomain is set up as it's own virtual site.

That will allow you to tell spiders not to index that subdomain. The catch is that I do not know how many crawlers currently support this header. A quick look indicates that Google and Yahoo! do.

Comment: Thank you for the answer - it is something I will keep in mind for the future, but it's not an option for this situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [meta robots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_element#The_robots_attribute) tag, which is supported by all of the major search engines today:

```html
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
```

I'm not exactly sure how to do this with robots.txt, though.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately it won't work in my case. All the sites share the same templates and I do not want to do a conditional each time a page is rendered to check for the subdomain.